# The effect of low pH on HIV virus

Tags: virology, amino-acids, hiv, retrovirus, ph

I've read a couple of articles that state that HIV is an enveloped Retrovirus that is so sensitive to the acidity of the environment and it cannot survive or will be inactivated at pH below 7. What exactly happens to the virus when exposed to an acidic environment. Does it denature the GP120 AND GP41 proteins on the virus envelope and make them ineffective? If not, how do hydrogen ions in the acid react with the virus?

Thanks for your attention.